# Is olive oil sold in supermarkets largely made from other oils?

Tags: nutrition

[This website](http://www.cracked.com/article_19896_the-6-creepiest-lies-food-industry-feeding-you.html) claims to reveal 6 lies that the food industry supposedly tells. The last one (after scrolling down to the bottom of the page) states

> As crazy as it sounds, olive oil piracy is one of the Italian Mafia's
>   most lucrative enterprises, to the extent that it appears that most
>   olive oil on the market is either greatly diluted or completely forged
>   by a massive shadow industry that involves major names such as
>   Bertolli.

and

> Today, the stuff that is pawned off to us as quality olive oil is
>   often just a tiny amount of the real thing, mixed with up to 80
>   percent of ordinary, less than healthy, cheap as muck sunflower oil.

I have never heard of this and have a hard time believing that this is possible, given how widely used olive oil is. Since neither sunflower nor other oils are listed at least on the bottles that I looked at, this would probably violate European laws about labelling.

Is there any truth to the claim that what is sold as olive oil in the world is largely made up of other oils?

Comment: Sold *where*? Italy? Spain? US of A? Siberia?

Comment: Olive oil expert Tom Mueller the author of "Extra Virginity: The Sublime and Scandalous World of Olive Oil" maintains a list on his blog of supermarket olive oils that are legitimately extra-virgin-http://www.truthinoliveoil.com/2012/09/toms-supermarket-picks-quality-oils-good-prices, so this claim cannot be determined as complete truth since there are olive oils which are genuinely extra-virgin in the market. More about the fakery can be read here-https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2012/jan/04/olive-oil-real-thing and here-http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2007/08/13/slippery-business.

Comment: There are 3 main olive oil types sold for human production. Extra virgin (cold extraction process without solvents or refining, undamaged olives used, acidity no higher than 0.8º), Virgin (similar to extra virgin, could not meet the extra virgin, acidity close to 1º) and Refined. Heating the olive destroys most of the benefitial organoleptic qualities so not all virgin olive oil qualifies as extra virgin and is the reason why you should not use extra virgin in a pan, consume extra virgin on its crude form.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The claim made by Cracked does have some truth to it, but it's referencing several different episodes, some of which involved passing off lesser olive oil as extra virgin.

Mafia involvement? Yes, but the oil was (lower quality) olive oil:

> About $42.8 million in assets were seized and charges filed against the suspects including mafia association, attempted murder, drug trafficking, money laundering and fraud, the police told the [Investigative Reporting Project](https://www.occrp.org/en/daily/6019-italian-carabinieri-arrest-33-suspected-members-of-a-ndrangheta-clan) of Italy.
>
> The Calabrian mafia, also known as the Ndràngheta, is believed to be the wealthiest, most powerful criminal network in Italy, and the Piromalli are believed to be a leading clan within that organization. In addition to drug trafficking, authorities believe they’re major players in agromafia, including an elaborate olive oil scheme.
>
> According to investigators, the Piromalli were importing olive pomace oil, a product that’s extracted from already-pressed fruit pulp using chemical solvents, then labeling the low-quality, adulterated oil products as extra virgin olive oil and exporting it to the U.S. Those products were sold through retail chains in New York, Boston and Chicago, the IRPI revealed.
>
> <sub>[Olive Oil Times](https://www.oliveoiltimes.com/olive-oil-business/italy-arrests-33-accused-olive-oil-fraud/55364)</sub>

80% sunflower oil? I think this refers to:

> Two Andalusian businessmen have been sentenced to two years in jail for their part in the distribution of hundreds of thousands of liters of fraudulent olive oil in Spain in 2005 and 2006.
>
> Passed off as extra virgin olive oil, prosecutors say the oil was actually **a mixture of 70-80 percent sunflower oil and just 20-30 percent olive oil**. During a hearing in the Córdoba provincial court in September they sought nine years jail and fines of 8,760 euros ($11,560) for each of the accused.
>
> <sub>[Olive Oil Times](https://www.oliveoiltimes.com/olive-oil-basics/jail-term-for-olive-oil-fraudsters/23081)</sub>

(You can read [the original source in Spanish](https://www.eldiadecordoba.es/cordoba/Aceptan-carcel-vender-aceite-fraudulento_0_542946428.html).)

These are just two of many incidents where extra virgin olive oil turned out to be adulterated. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olive_oil_regulation_and_adulteration#Investigations.2C_incidents.2C_and_recalls) lists more, one of which caused many deaths: "Almost 700 people died, it is believed, as a consequence of consuming rapeseed (canola) oil adulterated with aniline intended for use as an industrial lubricant, but sold in 1981 as olive oil in Spain".

As for "most of the market", I haven't been able to find any numbers.

Comment: +1: I've updated my answer to defer to your findings.

Answer (score 18):

No, it appears Cracked have got the real story confused.

There are two different issues:

- the adulteration of expensive olive oil with cheaper sunflower oil.
- the adulteration of expensive grades olive oils with *cheaper grades of olive oil*

[@Laurel's answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/37236/laurel) gives a good description of individual instances of the first issue. That shows it is a real problem.

However, that's quite different to Cracked's claim that "**Today**, the stuff that is pawned off to us as quality olive oil is **often** just a tiny amount of the real thing [...]"

The [UC Davis Olive Center](http://olivecenter.ucdavis.edu/) does research (with industry links) into olives and olive oil. For many years, they have been testing olive oils being sold in California for years to determine if they meet various standards, and they are somewhat critical of the purity of Extra-Virgin Olive Oils.

Their 2011 report, [*Evaluation of Extra-Virgin Olive Oil Sold in California*](http://olivecenter.ucdavis.edu/research/files/report041211finalreduced.pdf) said:

> While there are many excellent imported and domestic extra virgin olive oils available in California, our findings
>   indicate that the quality level of the largest imported brand names is inconsistent at best, and that most of the topselling
>   olive oil brands we examined regularly failed to meet international standards for extra virgin olive oil. [...] Of the five top-selling imported “extra virgin” olive oil brands in the United States, 73 percent of the samples
>   failed the IOC sensory standards for extra virgin olive oils analyzed by two IOC-accredited sensory panels.

But the reasons they gave for the failures did **not** include that it was adulterated with sunflower oil:

> Our testing indicated that the samples failed extra virgin olive oil standards for reasons that include one or more of the following: (a) oxidation by exposure to elevated temperatures, light, and/or aging; (b) adulteration with cheaper
>   refined olive oil; and (c) poor quality oil made from damaged and overripe olives, processing flaws, and/or improper oil storage.

[Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/food/ingredient/oliveoil.asp) draws a similar conclusion:

> The tested samples did not always meet the stringent extra-virgin standards for taste, aroma, and color, and the flavor profiles of some olive oils were likely overstated, but **the samples were not oils produced from another source masquerading as olive oil**, nor did the study raise concerns about purity, adulteration, safety, or substitution of various brands of olive oils.)

### Summary

Laurel's answer shows that there is indeed historical evidence of a problem with non-olive oils being mixed in with olive oils.

The UC Davis report shows that there is indeed a problem with cheaper grades of olive oils being mixed in with more expensive ones.

However, the UC Davis report also shows that the former issue is not common, and the second issue is (in California, at least).

Comment: Hmmm... Not convinced. That study did not test if it was olive oil or not. From my research, it is pretty clear that *some* percent of olive oil is adulterated (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olive_oil_regulation_and_adulteration), people have even died). The remaining question is *how much*.

Comment: @Laurel One of the tests done says "*Fatty acid profiles (FAP) are distinguishable markers between olive oils and some seed/nut oils (FAPs vary slightly depending on the varieties and growing region of olives).*" (Table 1) None of the reported oils failed FAP (Table 3).

Comment: It's worth to note that top-selling rarely means top-quality. Most often than not, the top-selling brand is also one of the cheapest. Having a top grade product makes it expensive, and that usually means that fewer people will purchase the item.

Comment: @TSar: Agreed, but the key words here aren't "top-selling" but "extra virgin", which is [the top grade](http://www.boundarybend.com/olive-oil/olive-oil-classification/).

Comment: There are several grades of extra virgin - what I mean is that, even among the best, there is the cheapest option.

Comment: @TSar: Okay. I'm looking through the answer trying to see if I have misstepped on this, but I can't see it. Is there something I should fix or add?

Comment: The citation you use takes a look at the "best selling" brands, not the premium ones. There isn't anything wrong with your answer, but the chosen methodology of the reference is biased towards failure - best selling usually means cheapest, which also means more prone to cut corners.

Comment: @TSar: Ahh, I see it now. Good point.

Comment: @Laurel I am spanish, so I can give some feedback on the persons that died. It was before olve oil regulations were put in place close to 40 years ago. Some dudes sold in Spain olive oil mixed with industrial lubricant, you can further read [about that incident and its consecuences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toxic_oil_syndrome).